# App Wakes Itself From Background

Tags: android, background, android-tv, android-background, amazon-fire-tv

I'm making an app for Android TV. I've came across a strange bug in that on Amazon Fire TV devices when you press the home/back button to minimise the app or send it into the background it will pop back up after about 10 seconds.

I'm not posting any code just now as to be totally honest I have no idea where to even start with the thousands of lines of code so posting it would just be a massive dump of code. Has anyone came across this issue and found a solution?

I've tested it on the Android Emulator running Android TV and the behaviour doesn't seem to occur there which makes it all the stranger.

The debug log shows this line overtime the app reawakens.

```
05-20 04:53:32.787 4663-4701/com.companyname.appname W/khrn_client: init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1
05-20 04:53:32.797 4663-4701/com.companyname.appname W/khrn_client: init_window window 0x51e72f20, 1920x1080 hintTransform 0x0 do_pre 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ran some more tests and the issue seems to be related to a runnable I have that fires every 10 minutes. Why it was firing 10 seconds after the app went into the background, and why it was only showing the issue on the Amazon Fire TV I still have no idea but so long as I manually stop the runnable in the onPause() function the issue seems to go away.